# IF statement in loop throwing syntax error

Tags: batch-file

I'm creating a small batch script that loops over lines in documents then selects the correct condition and print out related message.

This is what I have tried.

```
...
set /p action=enter action(send,receive)

FOR /F %%j IN (countryList.txt) DO (
 For /F %%k IN (ports.txt) DO (
     IF "%action%" == "send"( ECHO Script will run as send for %%j country on %%k port)
     ELSE IF "%action%" == "receive"( ECHO Script will run as receive for %%j country on %%k port)
)
)
echo END
```

I am using ELSE IF, because in real case there are more conditions than just send and receive.
I am expecting simple message out of ECHO.

Comment: I think you need `ELSE ( IF ... )`, since there is just `ELSE` and no `ELSE IF`

Comment: Using `Choice /C SR /M "Send or Receive"` would be a whole lot better, enter `choice /?` at the Command Prompt for its usage information. You should then do the same with `if /?` to find out how to use it too: `If /I "%action%" == "send" (Echo Script will run as send for %%j country on %%k port) Else Echo Script will run as receive for %%j country on %%k port`.

Comment: @ThomasWeller , even when I delete 'ELSE IF' and leave it just with one condition, the result is the same: **The syntax of the command is incorrect**.

Comment: `ECHO Script will run as %action% for %%j country on %%k port`. If you want to keep your `if`s (maybe there is more code than just `echo`), be sure to insert a space between `.."send"` and `(`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is with basic syntax; enter **`if /?`** at the Command Prompt for its usage information.

```bat
        If /I "%action%" == "send" (
            Echo Script will run as send for %%j country on %%k port
        ) Else (
            Echo Script will run as receive for %%j country on %%k port
        )
```